# See examples 1 and 2 in section X - or - See section X, examples 1 and 2

Tags: technical-writing, references

Which form is more common when referring to examples (or, for example, tables)?

> Some text (see examples 1a and 2e in *X*).

or

> Some text (see *X*, examples 1a and 2e).

*X* is the title of the section. The word "section" is not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of any standard.

But your first one reads easier to me:
See examples 1 and 2 in section X.